# Set all character variables in DF to blank

Tags: r

I've seen posts where the entire data frame is converted to character and then NA is removed. This is not desirable since the data frame in question contains numeric values and dates that require reconversion back to their original form. Is there a way to set up an array with specific variables in R to handle this all in one attempt without writing many lines of code in mutate statements or other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is best to "read" the dataframe already specifying the column type. For example, in a dataframe where we have name (character), age (double) and the date of birth, the right way to "read" the dataframe would be:

```
df = read_csv("df_name.csv", col_types = c("c", "d", "D"))
```

The col_types are generally read wrongly when the dataframe has a huge amount of NA is its beginning.

Comment: OP makes no mention of reading in a csv file. They refer only to a data frame.